# Find probability mass function and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $X_0,X_1,X_2,...$ be independent identically distributed
>   nonnegative random variables having a continuous distribution. Let $N$
>   be the first index $k$ for which $X_k>X_0$. That is, $N=1$ if $X_1>X_0, N=2$ if $X_1≤X_0$ and $X_2>X_0$,etc.
>
> Determine the probability mass function for $N$ and the mean
>   $\mathbb{E}N$.
>
> Interpretation: $X_0,X_1,X_2,...$ are successive offers or bids on a car that you are trying to sell. Then $N$ is the index of the first bid that is better than the initial bid.

This should not be too complicated, however I tried some different approaches with these conditional probabilities and I am really stuck on this task. I do not know how to handle it since the exact distribution of the random variables is not given. It appears that I have too little information.

Any kind of help or advice will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Since $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid, given $X_0$, $X_i-X_0$ will be independent of $X_j-X_0$ for non-zero $i$ and $j$ s.t. $i\neq j$. Also, suppose that $F(x)$ is the cdf of $X_i$.

$$
\begin{align}
P\{N = i|X_0=x\} &= P\{X_i>X_0, (X_{j}\leq X_0; 0 < j < i)|X_0=x\}\\
&= P\{X_i>X_0|X_0=x\}\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}P\{X_j \leq X_0|X_0=x\}\\
&= (1-F(x))F(x)^{i-1}
\end{align}
$$

$$\mathbb{E}(N|X_0=x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i(1-F(x))F(x)^{i-1} = (1-F(x))\frac{1}{(1-F(x))^2} = \frac{1}{1-F(x)}$$

$$\mathbb{E}N = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(N|X_{0})) = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{1-F(X_0)}\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}dx \rightarrow \infty$$

**Edit**:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{N=i\} &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\{N=i|X_0=x\}f(x)dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))F(x)^{i-1}f(x)dx\\
&= \left(\frac{F(x)^i}{i}-\frac{F(x)^{i+1}}{i+1}\right)\bigg\vert_{0}^{\infty}\\
&= \frac{1}{i(i+1)}
\end{align}
$$

Verifying $\mathbb{E}N$,

$$\mathbb{E}N = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{i(i+1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i+1} \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: You computed the conditional probability mass function of $N$ while the question asks for the unconditional one, I think. In addition, you condition on an event having probability zero...

Comment: I am actually not sure. What would be the unconditional one?

Comment: @Fullbright check edit.